# preventing bad and needed recursion

Tags: c, recursion, embedded, state

I have a problem with here:

```
void DrawState(){
    char statevar[1000] = {0};
    //bla bla bla
    something = showmenu(); // or showscreen() or showinput() 
    if(something){ 
       // change state
       state = new_state;
    }else{
       // return to previous state
       state = return_state;
    }
    // draw new state here.
    DrawState();
}
```

I need this function to run when state changes. But when I do write like this recursively, it consumes too much memory and eventually it crashes the system. When I don't do this, I don't have any idea how to call itself from outside.

Does someone have any idea?

**Edit:** This is a library that runs over a manager software, like a plugin. Background jobs need to work too with this implementation. Maybe I should run this on some event.

Comment: how does the state eventually end?  That is why it crashes, you keep calling the function and there is no end to it.  You need some sort of return when `state` reaches its goal.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use `DrawState` as a *callback* (using an observer), rather than writing it recursively.

Comment: I enter this method on start and it handles all the states while it's running. It doesn't end.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski yes.

Comment: Why not use a simple loop instead of recursion?

Comment: Yes I thought that too, but what really confuses me here is the background workers running. If I use a while loop, I think it may not give them a chance to run. BTW, I forgot to mention this is a library running on a manager software. Sorry.

Comment: an infinitely recursive function call won't give other code more chance to run than a never-ending loop.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yes, you're right. That's why I'm trying to avoid them.

Comment: if these background workers are in a separate thread, you have nothing to worry about. Otherwise, you'll have to read the manager software documentation to find out how to give the background workers their fair slice of cpu time. Either way, the loop still sounds like the better idea.

Comment: If you write code like this for embedded systems, complete and utter stack overflow is the least of your problems.

Comment: what do you suggest for an event driven state machine design then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want doesn't involve recursion, per se, but rather simply a callback.

When you need to run some code whenever something in your code changes, you want to implement the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  A simple C implementation might use a function pointer to hold the function that will be run when the data monitored is updated.

For example, you could separate your update function:

```
void DrawState() {
    // ... 
}
```

And then, you could maintain a pointer to it

```
int (*updateDraw)() = DrawState
```

And then do...

```
if (updated) {
  // when updated
  updateDraw()
}
```

Comment: if I call the pointer method inside `DrawState()`, will it act like it's running at top of the stack? I mean exiting the parent `DrawState()` and running it again?

Comment: updates become inside DrawState method, so calling updateDraw function pointer still means recursion, right? I mean, copying the third code box inside first one.

Comment: @TahaPaksu move the updates so that they do *not* come in the updateDraw function.  There should be no need for recursion here.  Typically the story is that you have an infinite loop that responds to events, it checks some property, and appropriately dispatches the right handlers.

Comment: "Observer pattern"? This is called _polling_ and has been called that for at least 40 years. A rose by any other name...

Comment: @Lundin: *polling* refers to the method of checking the variable (which, in particular, usually indicates code smell, since there are generally other ways). Observers refer to the way in which watchers are notified.  "The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes."  However, if you feel compelled to correct me, feel free to edit my answer: I'm not implying that calling it the observer pattern rather than polling is the core part of the answer.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski Whatever. In my experience, design patterns is all about coming up with new names for already existing things. Why someone needs a fancy name for something so fundamental as checking a flag and then calling a function, I don't know. There's nothing brilliant or magical about it.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not trying to harp on design patterns: if you have a personal aversion to them (I do!), I'm not trying to force them upon you.  I merely included the term in my answer because I honestly believe that the OP may benefit from googling about it and finding other related examples.  I believe googling "polling" will not be as helpful (because it's such a general term).  But like I said, the critical part is using a callback, regardless of whether you just call it polling or an observer.